# Keep background audio from other apps alive, react-native-video IOS

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-video

long time listener first time caller.

I am so far unsuccessful in getting background music from something like Spotify to stay alive in my react-native app as soon as I navigate to a screen that is using react-native-video.  On Android no changes had to be made for that to work.  I am using react-native (non-expo) and am currently in testing on testflight.

If this is a duplicate let me know, but I am only finding many articles on how to make your app play in the background (my issue is the opposite), and I may not just know the term IOS uses for this type of control.  Important to note that one instance of this component *DOES* include audio, but the majority of videos presented have no audio.

I've tried:

1. updating AppDelgate.m with the instructions from react-native-video docs:

AppDelegate.m

```
    #import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>  // import
    
     - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
      ...
      [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:nil];  // allow
      ...
    }
```

- this had seemingly no effect

2. Using `ignoreSilentSwitch="ignore"` and `obey`

- `Obey` successfully allows background audio to continue, but mutes the videos that do have audio.
- Looking at the source, ignoreSilentSwitch=obey does the same thing as what I added to the AppDelegate.m file and is also negated if you use the isPaused prop.
- Tried many of the other props involving audio hoping to get lucky.

3. Added Background Modes = "Audio, Airplay, and Picture in Picture" Capability on my app target in xcode.
4. Cried a little bit and questioned my life choices.

I implemented react-native-video using react-native-video-controls, but as I understand it's the same module with added features. Here is the implemenation:

```
<VideoContainer>
    <VideoPlayer
      source={currentVideo}
      navigator={null}
      ref={videoRef}
      resizeMode={'cover'}
      controlTimeout={1500}
      paused={isPaused}
      repeat={true}
      muted={true}
      tapAnywhereToPause={true}
      disableBack={true}
      disableTimer={true}
      disableVolume={true}
      disableFullscreen={true}
      showOnStart={true}
      hideShutterView={true}
    />
 </VideoContainer>
```

Any help, suggestion, feedback or rebuttal is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Culprit found.

So I am using react-native-audio for certain timed sounds that overlay muted and non-muted videos.

When you call the react-native-sound Sound.setCategory() method, the optional 2nd argument is a 'mix-with-other's bool.  Setting that to true and following the react-native-video suggested AVAudioSession config in the AppDelegate.m was all I needed.

IOS categories (other than the suggested Playback in react-native-sound):
[ios sound categories](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/AudioSessionCategoriesandModes/AudioSessionCategoriesandModes.html)

[Similar issue that helped me find mine](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video/issues/1095)

Helpful IOS docs on audio:

[this one](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_playback_and_selection/configuring_ios_and_tvos_audio_playback_behavior)

[and this one](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/category/1616509-playback)

Answer (score 2):

I think there is a prop

```
mixWithOthers
```

try setting it to 'mix'

Answer (score 2):

adding these 3 props works:

```
<Video
    ...
    ignoreSilentSwitch="obey"
    muted={true}
    disableFocus
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

For iOS:

- [Enable Background Audio](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Audio/Conceptual/AudioSessionProgrammingGuide/AudioSessionBasics/AudioSessionBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007875-CH3-SW3) in your Xcode project

Is using `react-native-video` you should also add:

- Set the ignoreSilentSwitch prop to "ignore"

Answer (score -1):

I'm seeing that you are missing the prop to enable backgroundAudio. Quoting the docs:

playInBackground
Determine whether the media should continue playing while the app is in the background. This allows customers to continue listening to the audio.

false (default) - Don't continue playing the media

true - Continue playing the media
To use this feature on iOS, you must:

Enable Background Audio in your Xcode project
Set the ignoreSilentSwitch prop to "ignore"
Platforms: Android ExoPlayer, Android MediaPlayer, iOS

Comment: Thanks Menethor! Yeah I threw that one in as well in one of my many attempts and it definitely does work for Android, I've posted my answer for the IOS issue I was having.